# "How does he does/do that?"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, questions, verb-agreement, do-support

> How does he does that?
>
> How does he do that?

Which one is correct? This type of sentence sounds a little odd because of two *do/does* in a single statement. Is there an alternative which has the same meaning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct sentence is

> How does he do that?

In the same way one writes

> How does he run?
>
> How does he fly?

Comment: (Instead of *How does he runs?* and *How does he flies?*)

Answer (score 2):

As @Jasper said, the answer is

> How does he do that?

The first "does" is the [auxiliary verb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_verb) which allows to turn the sentence into a question. The second "do" is the verb of the action in itself, which is not conjugated because the conjugation is applied to the auxiliary verb.

The sentence is perfectly correct. If you feel awkward about how it sounds, you could say for example:

> How can he do that?